# Crystal Reports select expert OR statement on CSV

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using the Select Expert to filter on a combination of 3 fields:

```
 ({flatfile_csv.site} = "L" and {flatfile_csv.bursguar} = "1")
 or
 ({flatfile_csv.site} = "L" and {flatfile_csv.bursnorm} = "1")
```

In this case it only matches:

```
 ({flatfile_csv.site} = "L" and {flatfile_csv.bursguar} = "1")
```

If I swap the statements around:

```
 ({flatfile_csv.site} = "L" and {flatfile_csv.bursnorm} = "1")
 or
 ({flatfile_csv.site} = "L" and {flatfile_csv.bursguar} = "1")
```

Then it only handles

```
 ({flatfile_csv.site} = "L" and {flatfile_csv.bursnorm} = "1")
```

It seems to completely ignore the second part of the OR statement.  Any idea how to implement an OR in CR?

Comment: Can `{flatfile_csv.bursguar}` or `{flatfile_csv.bursnorm}` be null?

Comment: they can be an empty string.  It's feeding from a CSV file, so they can be "".  not sure how CR deals with this

Comment: Try:  `(({flatfile_csv.site} = "L" and {flatfile_csv.bursnorm} = "1") or ({flatfile_csv.site} = "L" and {flatfile_csv.bursguar} = "1"))` - entire condition enclosed in ().  Does that change anything?

Comment: no difference I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used CR with a CSV file before, so I don't know how it's handling those empty strings. Try setting the selection formula to "Default Values for Nulls" instead of "Exception for Nulls" with this:

```
{flatfile_csv.site} = "L"
and
  (
   {flatfile_csv.burnsnorm}="1"
   or {flatfile_csv.burnsguar}="1"
  )
```

Comment: the formula suffers the same issues I'm afraid.  Where can you:Try setting the selection formula to "Default Values for Nulls" instead of "Exception for Nulls"

Comment: EDIT - found it in the formula editor view at the top, it works! Thanks!